# Automated process flow testing for each process in JBPM Business-central

Tags: java, jbpm, bpmn, businesscentral

Can we conduct automated process flow testing for each process in JBPM Business-central, both for "direct flow" and for "processes that need input to progress" without manual intervention?

Are there any available options for this? How to proceed with this?